# Organizar dados no excel

Tags: r, csv

Tenho um arquivo com 59 observações e com 93 variáveis em arquivo Excel e transformei para .csv. para criar a tabela no R, contudo as minhas 93 variáveis aparecem em uma mesma coluna. Como faço para que elas apareçam separadas?

Answer (score 2):

Tente rodar o comando

```
read.table(file="nomedoarquivo.csv", header=T, sep=",")
```

Este comando vai funcionar se o seu arquivo tiver as colunas nomeadas. Se as colunas não forem nomeadas, substitua o argumento header=T por header=F.

Answer (score 1):

Se você salvou .csv a partir de um excel em português, deve usar `read.csv2`. Em relação ao `read.csv`, ele muda porque usa `sep = ";"` e `dec = ","`, que é o padrão não-americano.

Vale a pena usar também `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` para evitar bagunça com as colunas não numéricas:

```
read.csv2("arquivo.csv", stringsAsFacotrs = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Leia direto do Excel usando o pacote `readxl`

```
read_excel("arquivo.xlsx")
```

Você ainda pode usar o argumento `sheet` se sua planilha tiver varias abas.
Leia o help usando `?read_excel`. E antes de tudo isso não esqueça de instalar o pacote: `install.packages("readxl")`.

A leitura direto do excel tem a vantagem de já ler corretamente números, datas e strings sem que você tenha que salvar o `.csv`.